# "clear screen" function clears measurement components but changes the layer order

Tags: openlayers, measurements

My work environment:
OpenLayers 2.13.1,
.Net Razor (*.cshtml),
IIS 8.5 and Windows Server 2012 R2.

When the **"clear screen"** function works after making a measurement on the map, the measurement components are cleared, **but the order of the layers on the map changes.**

Screenshot/GIF: [image]

My CleanModules.js:

```
   var CleanModules = {};
if (canli) {
    CleanModules.menuInnerHTML = '<li><a href="#" id="cleaner" onclick="$(\'iframe\')[3].contentWindow.hide();$(\'iframe\')[3].contentWindow.CleanModules.CleanScreen();"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Ekranı Temizle</a></li>';
} else {
    CleanModules.menuInnerHTML = '<li><a href="#" id="cleaner" onclick="hide();CleanModules.CleanScreen();"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Ekranı Temizle</a></li>';
}
//$(menuolcumaraclariid, WindowParent).after(CleanModules.menuInnerHTML);


CleanModules.CleanScreen = function () { // Ekrandaki Tüm Katmanları temizleme
    
     $('.MeasureDiv').removeClass('MeasureDivActive');
     MeasureModules.measureControls["line"].deactivate();
     MeasureModules.measureControls["polygon"].deactivate();
    
    //LayerTreeModules.redrawLayers();
    var Layers = ["Vector", "Drawing", "Text", "Markers", "Thematic", "POI","Query"]
    
    
    for (i = 0; i < Layers.length; i++) {
        try {
            Layer[Layers[i]].removeAllFeatures();
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                Layer[Layers[3]].clearMarkers();
            }
            catch (e) {

            }
        }
    }
}


CleanModules.CleanScreenTwo = function () {
    window.parent.document.getElementById('map').src += '';
};
```

So i don't want the layer order to change when the measurement results are cleared. Can you help me please?